# How can I find the minimum browser requirement for JsTree 3.1.1

Tags: jquery, firefox, jstree, minimum-requirements

I am trying to figure out the minimum requirement for my application which is using JsTree 3.1.1

Is it any way to find out the very first browser version that supports features used in JsTree 3.1.1?

Bonus: In general, how can I find the minimum requirements if the documentation does not exists. e.g. maybe a tool that try the application using different version of FF and test the test cases.

Comment: I found in http://caniuse.com/ , we can find browser compatibility of some CSS, HTML and JS features. But, I am not sure which features JSTree is using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is right there on http://jstree.com (the browser icons) - all modern browsers + IE8 and up.

If you are looking for a specific version of firefox (as I see it as a tag) - I believe Firefox 3 (which is old enough not to be mentioned).

Keep in mind IE8 support is OK (you may lack some visual sugar, but it will work properly), provided you are not in quirks mode or compatibility mode.

---

**Edit**: The minimum Firefox version is 3.5, as jstree needs `document.querySelector`

Comment: The question is what "Modern Browser" means? 
How can I know from which version of FF, it is called "modern"!

Comment: It is a common practice to specify requirements like this, ever since browsers adopted frequent and silent updates. Still I believe I answered your question - FF3 works, I also tested in Chrome 14 (as it was the lowest version I could find), the same goes for Opera 12 and Safari 4. I also added a note on the site, which will be live in a few hours.

Comment: I updated the note - it is Firefox 3.5, as some features use `document.querySelector`, which is the most "advanced" feature jstree uses, so Chrome 1 will also probably work, but I can not be sure. Also - the note on the site is already live - thank you for pointing out the need for more information.